# A dice is biased that it is twice as likely to show an even number.when it is thrown twice then find the probability of getting an even sum?

Tags: probability

My attempt

$3x+6x=1,x=1/9$

Sum is even when the two numbers are either odd or even.probability of getting even sum$=6\times (2/9)\times (2/9)+6\times (1/9)\times 1/9=10/27$
But the answer is $5/9$ how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had done the same thing for the probability of an odd number, you might have said something like

$6\times (2/9)\times (1/9)+6\times (1/9)\times (2/9)=8/27$

but this would be wrong as $10/27 + 8/27 \not=1$

Instead, your original calculation might better have been something like

$(2/3)\times (2/3)+(1/3)\times (1/3) = 5/9$

perhaps from

$(3\times 2/9)\times (3\times 2/9)+ (3\times 1/9)\times (3\times 1/9) = 5/9$

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake...we can get same outcomes during multiple throw

Comment: And in first case that you have mentioned it should be like 3C1*3C1(2/9)*(1/9)*2

Comment: @Akulsharma: yes though personally I would do $(2/3)\times (1/3)+(1/3)\times (2/3)$ - they both give you $4/9$, and note $5/9+4/9=1$ as you would expect

Comment: Exactly...thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{even}) = \frac23$, $P(\text{odd})=\frac13$

$P(\text{even sum}) = P(\text{even})\times P(\text{even}) + P(\text{odd})\times P(\text{odd}) = \frac59$